# Live reload feature on Mobile device for PWA app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

I need to develop a Mobile PWA app. I use Ionic/Capacitor. I know how to run the native app on a device with live reload feature. But how can I do the same with a mobile web app? i.e. I would like to develop PWA on advice from the beginning.

I use this with Native Android apps:

> ionic cap run android -l --host=0.0.0.0

Comment: On same Wifi use `ionic serve --external` you will see external Ip in your terminal. Use that ip in your chrome to view your app.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib It is working. Please put it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve your ionic app on local Lan via same Wifi you can use Command:

`ionic serve --external`

you will see external IP address in your terminal use that IP in your Mobile Device Browser.